# Identify geographical locations within 10 miles logic

Tags: geolocation

im about to start developing an application and im stuck on the most efficient way to do a task. So anyone can access this app and say hey im here! on the map. Their geographical location (long, lat) will be used as a kind of marker.

Now when a user access's this app, how would it display the markers that people have been to within say a 10 mile radius. Sure i could use a for loop to scroll though every single marker but on a scale much bigger would that be the most efficient way? What if there was 50,000 markers.

I then thought to add a country to each marker so it only scrolls through the markers of the country you are in, but even then i would have to scroll though every single marker, check if they are in the same country and then the location unless i make a database for every single country which just seems wrong.

Not looking for actual code just the logic on how existing applications already do this, thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database with standard float indices for `long` and `lat`  (e.g. using MySQL), you can select all points, which are within certain longitude and latitude intervals. For this, you should first calculate, which `Delta_Longitude` and `Delta_Latitude` corresponds to 10miles (DeltaLongitude is latitude dependent). The result set consists of all points on a *square* centered around the marker (since the square is on a sphere, it is not really a square).

This query narrowed down the selection by a large factor, It should be feasible to calculate the [distance on a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) now for each point and filter the markers again.

---

MongoDB features [geospatial indixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-indexes), which do exectaly what you were asking for.

Comment: ah thats perfect i never thought about doing it straight from sql. Im sure i could use google maps api or something to work out this delta lat and long, thanks alot :)

Comment: Relying on a established framework is probably a good idea to calculate the angles, because you also have to deal with boundary cases: `359° + 2° = 1° `